# Casperjs test if page opens

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

It can be done with pure phantomjs like this:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
var address = 'http://google.com/';
page.open(address, function(status) {
  if (status !== 'success') {
    console.log('FAIL to load the address');
  } else {
    console.log('SUCCESS');
  }
  phantom.exit();
});
```

but I'd like it to support `casperjs test` command. The best I came up with is:

```
casper.test.begin("Hello, Test!", 1, function(test) {
    var page = require('webpage').create();
    var address = 'http://google_doesnotexist.com/';
    page.open(address, function(status) {
        test.assert(status == 'success');
        //phantom.exit();
        test.done();
    });
});
```

it works fine if page really opens, but the script does not stop at all if the page does not open.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apart from your [own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24818325/1816580), you can explicitly check the status through the [`status` function](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#status):

```
casper.start("http://www.example.com/", function() {
    test.assert(this.status().currentHTTPStatus == 200);
});
```

or even easier by using the [tester module](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/tester.html#asserthttpstatus) as you already do this:

```
casper.start("http://www.example.com/", function() {
    test.assertHttpStatus(200);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no example with function argument in casperjs docs, but I've guessed it right:)

```
casper.test.begin('Page opens fine', 1, function suite(test) {
    casper.start("http://www.google_nononon.com/", function(result) {
        //console.log(status);
        //require('utils').dump(status);
        test.assert(result.status == 200);
    });

    casper.run(function() {
        test.done();
    });
});
```